# Eclipse neon-ui-workbench null pointer exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, forms, eclipse-plugin

Getting null pointer exception as main form design is not opening. Tried to clean projects and tried restarting did not work.

This is the error i recieved

[image]

on sending report this error was shown in browser

Bug 532524  - SWTException below FormImages$AbstractImageDescriptor. (thrown in Color.getRGB)

Comment: can any one help?

Comment: The error appears to be in EntireJ so probably need to contact them. I'm not sure that bug 532524 is relevant but that was fixed in Eclipse 4.8 (Photon)

Comment: yes but i am using eclipse neon 2 and although it is a bug , on right click the java form and open with window builder has been the alternative to opening forms.